# preg_match: and-not expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a text with line breaks, and I need to check if it has some word, but doesn't have another.

For example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
>   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

If the text has word "lorem" AND "ipsum", no matter in wich line, then test should fail. If the text contains "lorem" but does not have "ipsum" on any line, then it should succeed.

I may probably do some workaround, and make tests with conditions, *explode* and *strpos* functions. But I want to use regex rules as a predefined presets, so I can easily extend functionality.

Comment: Tried something like `if(!preg_match("/(lorem.*?ipsum|ipsum.*?lorem)/is", $str)) { /* code */ }`?

Comment: What about word boundaries, case sensitivity? I'd go with `^(?si)(?!.*\blorem\b.*\bipsum\b|\bipsum\b.*\blorem\b.*$).*$` if you are happy with the string match when `ipsum` is present and `lorem` is not.  See https://regex101.com/r/lB5qX5/1.

Comment: @WarGasm You seem to be commenting almost everything that doesn't work and not the only on that's actually doing what you asked. GL.

Comment: So are you saying that `lorem` is required? Because when I read your question I see `if it contains lorem, it can't contain ipsum`, not `it must contain lorem, but not ipsum`. Saying "if the text has..." to me means that it is optional, not required. If it is required, then a simple pattern like this would work: `/(?=.*lorem)(?!.*ipsum).*/is` which means `must have lorem, can't have ipsum`. Add all the boundary stuff as well. it is already multiline. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uN2jN6/3)

Comment: You accepted an answer that matches a sentence without lorem as required in your question, Actually, the accepted answer matches : "nothing" and "absolutely nothing", that's really sad (for you).

Comment: @PedroLobito I'm commenting solutions that are more closer to what I need. It is not difficult to split the lines and find words. The main problem was to solve this with a single regex rule.

Comment: @PedroLobito I have accepted the solution that was fixed in the comments by the author.

Comment: @WarGasm It solved what you need but not what you asked.

Comment: @PedroLobito I'm sorry for poorly described problem. Anyway, thank you for taking part.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn `/(?=.*lorem)(?!.*ipsum).*/is` works fine too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggested regex does not require `!` with `preg_match`, and matches only a multiline string without both "lorem" and "ipsum" in any upper or lower case and as *whole words*:

```
^(?si)(?!.*?\bipsum\b.*$)(?!.*\blorem\b.*\bipsum\b|\bipsum\b.*\blorem\b.*$).*$
```

`(?si)` sets case-insensitive and singleline modes so that `.` could match a newline and match both "Lorem" and "lorem". `\b`s are used to match whole words only. It will also fail a string that has `ipsum` (a second condition `(?!.*?\bipsum\b.*$)` is set to handle that).

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/lB5qX5/1)

```
$re = "/^(?si)(?!.*?\\bipsum\\b.*$)(?!.*\\blorem\\b.*\\bipsum\\b|\\bipsum\\b.*\\blorem\\b.*$).*$/"; 
$str = "dolor lorem sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, \nsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."; 
if (preg_match($re, $str, $matches)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: The SO asked to "If the text contains "lorem" but does not have "ipsum" on any line, then it should succeed". Try it without lorem and ipsum and it also matches. This returns true `dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit`

Comment: According to your requirements, it should. If you do not want it, use `^(?si)(?!.*?\bipsum\b.*$)(?!.*\blorem\b.*\bipsum\b|\bipsum\b.*\blorem\b.*$).*$` - https://regex101.com/r/lB5qX5/4. EDITED 2.

Comment: @PedroLobito right, but try to leave "lorem" in your demo and you will get match. It is not "AND-NOT" logic.

Comment: That's exactly what the SO wants a match where `lorem` exists but not `ipsum`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
lorem[\s\S]*ipsum|ipsum[\s\S]lorem
```

**[working demo](https://regex101.com/r/uN2jN6/1)**

```
$re = "/lorem[\\s\\S]*ipsum|ipsum[\\s\\S]lorem/i"; 
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."; 

if (!preg_match($re, $str, $matches)) {
     // your code here
}
```

**Update:** you can achieve the same without negating the preg_match as **[Jonathan Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333074/jonathan-kuhn)** pointed in his comment:

> Also, if you wanted to make this work without needing to negate the preg_match you could wrap it in a zero-width negative group like: `^(?!lorem[\s\S]*ipsum|ipsum[\s\S]lorem).*$`. This will match the entire string where both words don't exist. **[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uN2jN6/2)** (shows as not matching until you remove one of the words).

Comment: Also, if you wanted to make this work without needing to negate the preg_match you could wrap it in a zero-width negative group like: `^(?!lorem[\s\S]*ipsum|ipsum[\s\S]lorem).*$`. This will match the entire string where both words don't exist. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uN2jN6/2) (shows as not matching until you remove one of the words).

Comment: Almost suitable, thanks for replying. But it needs "not" operator for preg_match. How can I leave it? The problem is in another tests. I have an array of rules and want to include this test to the one cycle of preg_match.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn very useful, thanks. Have just added to the answer

Comment: @WarGasm have updated the answer with Jonathan comments

Comment: @WarGasm Is that not something you want? Because you don't say anything about that in the requirements.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn AND-NOT is a logical operator that works only one way. If (A & !B). Only B, or other variants should fail. Also, it must ignore line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$str = "Lorem my string ipsum";
if (preg_match("/lorem/", $str) && !preg_match("/ipsum/", $str)) {
    //code here
}
```

It is easier to make 2 different regex pattern, than have a single long regex

Comment: Missing delimeters. Also, if you are searching for only one word, `stripos` would be better. This also doesn't account for `ipsum` with no `lorem`.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Oops, sorry. I am unfamiliar with PHP, just know regex. Thank you for noticing

Comment: The key is that it's often easier to split up your task into two invocations of different regexes rather than trying to cram all of your work into a single regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string ="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore ipsum et dolore magna aliqua.";

$string2 ="Lorem dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";

loremIpsum  ($string );
//string contrains lorem and ipsum
loremIpsum  ($string2 );
//string only contrain lorem

function loremIpsum  ($string){
    if (!preg_match('/(lorem.*?ipsum|ipsum.*?lorem)/sim', $string)) {

        if (preg_match('/lorem/sim', $string )) {
            # Successful match
            echo "string only contain lorem"; // TRUE
        }else{
            echo "string doesn't contain lorem"; //FALSE
        }

    }else{
        echo "string contrains lorem and ipsum"; //FALSE
    }
}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/vfPBif)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Actually it would be good if regex has a and operator but at least i do not know such a thing, so you can match them in regex with or operator and then using array_intersect to check.

```
$checkArray = array ('lorem', 'ipsum');
$haystack = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";

$matched = preg_match_all("/lorem|ipsum/i", $haystack, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

if ($matched && count($checkArray) == count(array_intersect($checkArray,$result[0]))) {
    echo "Gotcha";
}
```